# Fokker-Planck counterpart of Grönwall inequality/comparison theorem

Tags: partial-differential-equations, reference-request, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, heat-equation

In the analysis of SDE's, the famous [Grönwall inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6nwall%27s_inequality#Integral_form_for_continuous_functions) (or other types of [more advanced comparison theorems](https://ir.library.osaka-u.ac.jp/repo/ouka/all/7664/ojm14_03_14.pdf)) is often useful to bound solutions by replacing e.g. the drift term by a larger, but more "transparent", drift term: e.g. such a replacement could turn a non-autonomous SDE into an autonomous one and it could help e.g. in establishing [tightness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tightness_of_measures) of a certain family of probability measures depending on a time-parameter.

Turning to the Markov transition functions (governed by a Fokker-Planck equation), the one-sided repercussions on individual trajectories after replacing the drift-term should carry over into "one-sided" repercussions for those transition functions. Unfortunately, I don't know the techniques or the names of the techniques which mirror the use of the Grönwall inequality on the Fokker-Planck side. Any suggestions?